# Is feature selection agnostic to regression/classification model chosen?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, regression

So as the title suggests, my question is whether feature selection algorithms are independent of the regression/classification model chosen. Maybe some feature selection algorithms are independent and some are not? If so can you name a few of each kind? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the algorithm you use to select features.  Filter methods that are done prior to modeling are of course agnostic, as they're using statistical methods like chi-squared or correlation coefficient to get rid of unnecessary features.

If you use embedded methods where features are selected during model creation, it is possible that different models will find value in different feature sets.  Lasso, Elastic Net, Ridge Regression are a few examples of these.

It's worth noting that some model types perform well with sparse data or missing values while others do not.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What about wrapper methods like forward selection and backward elimination?

Comment: Forward/backward selection procedures often use similar statistical tests to chi-squared/correlation coefficients, usually in the form of an F-test. @gst1502

Comment: Gradient boosting will almost certainly find different value in features when compared to something like logistic regression.  Even if they have the same optimal feature set, the importance of each individual feature will be different to each model.

Comment: So is it safe to assume that they converge to the same optimal feature set?

Comment: I would not assume such a thing no, which is why embedded methods are useful, as they're going to generate feature lists on a per model basis.  Once you are happy w/the model, you can reduce the feature set going forward.

Comment: What is the best way to limit number of features to a fixed number @Chris? Are there any embedded methods which do this?